# Add Tuple of over 7 to List

Tags: c#

I have this List:

```
public List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string,string,string>>>> Load = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string,string,string>>>>();
```

I'm trying to add values to this list I've tried multiple ways currently I have:

```
Load.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>("1","2","3","4","5","6","7",Tuple.Create("8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"),Tuple.Create("16","17","18","19","20")));
```

This isn't really working for me though, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" You're abusing `Tuple` to the point where it will cause the highest and most unpleasant cognitive load to anyone reading/working with your code. Just create a class with (named... yay!) properties and use that instead of Tuple.

Comment: Why not `List<List<string>>` or `List<string[]>`?

Comment: maintainability hell detected: `Load[0].Item8.Item8.Item3`

Comment: Ah...I think that would work List<string[]>....@spender can you elaborate on your suggestion please.

Comment: @chancelance can you please describe what kind of data you want to store in list? why there is 7 items, then another group of 7 items, last of which is itself group. Why do you have these three groups of strings? What those strings mean?

Comment: Why not create a class instead of Tuple?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy...I have them in 7 cause you can't have more than 7 that is what the MS doc read. I think I'm going to go with the array option though seems a lot simpler and nicer to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a Tuple in C# is effectively a poor-man's class and serves as a great tool for making unreadable code. Should be used when you can't be bothered to write a more explicit structure... i.e. very rarely. If you're using more than two or three item Tuples, your code will very quickly become incomprehensible.

All of the strings you are storing must have some meaning. Do you really want to refer back to `myTuple.Item8.Item8.Item3` as suggested in the comments? What is each item in your tuple?

Are they just a bunch of related strings? In which case, use an `ICollection<string>`... `List<string>` might be appropriate here.

Does each item have a specific role? In which case, a class would be more appropriate:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public string Make{get;set;}
    public string Model{get;set;}
    public string Size{get;set;}
    //...etc
}
```

and now make a `List<MyThing>` and add instances of `MyThing` to it:

```
myList.Add(new MyThing{
    Make = "Volvo",
    Model = "940",
    Size = "Massive"
})
```

Now, at a single glance, it's very easy to understand the intent of the code.

Comment: This looks super clean and I agree...it was getting very ugly. Thanks for the explanation